# Haxm installation not compatible for windows 8.what would be the issue?

Tags: android

Installation of Haxm is incomplete and getting a error message " not compatible for windows 8". What would be the issue and please suggest me with solution

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the latest version directly from Intel:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager